# How do I reshape a character vector based on the contents in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a series of character vectors in which for every participant (denoted in ReprEx as a letter), there is a time point (in RePrex either 1 or 2), and then a score. Here is the ReprEx:

```
l <- c("A","1","27","B","1","26","2","54")
```

How can I reshape the vector to create a dataframe that has three columns, with Column A as participant, Column B as Time Point, and Column C as Score?

The intended output would like something like this:

```
data.frame("Participant" = c("A","B","B"),
           "Time Point" = c("1","1","2"),
           "Score" = c("27","26","54"))
```

If easier to make, it could be brought into this shape:

```
data.frame("Participant" = c("A","B"),
           "TimePoint1" = c("27","26"),
           "TimePoint2" = c("NA","54"))
```

Any direction/thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Are you missing the `"C"`?

Comment: Are you missing a `Participant` in `l` or this is how it is? There is no additional `"B"` ?

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I have edited the OP, sorry for the confusion, Participant B has two time points, although the "B" is not listed on the second time point as it follows sequentially.

Comment: @RonakShah That is how the data is unfortunately, where if the Participant is not listed, it is assumed it is what the previous time point entry is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way in base R.

Based on some pattern in `Participant` name we can find their position using `grep`. In the example shared the pattern is every `Participant` has an upper-case letter. We use their position to `split` data so each `Participant` has their own list. We use the first value in each list as `Participant` name and alternate values as `Time.point` and `Score` respectively.

```
output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(l, 
             findInterval(seq_along(l), grep('[A-Z]', l))), function(x) {
             data.frame(Participant = x[1], 
                         Time.Point = x[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
                         Score = x[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)])
         }))
rownames(output) <- NULL
output <- type.convert(output)
output

#  Participant Time.Point Score
#1           A          1    27
#2           B          1    26
#3           B          2    54
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks very much!